# WordPress Pages VERSUS WordPress Categories

Tags: wordpress, categories

I have a few questions here since I'm just new to `WordPress` so I hope you can help me in a way that I won't be confused in the instructions.

1. I have *Pages* on my main menu. We all know that *Pages* are static, accepts only 1 post. My pages are Home, Dear Diary, Hobbies, Career Building, About and Contact. Every post goes to Home. Now, if I post new posts I just want it to appear in this certain page and won't appear in Home. Say, I have a new post with a title "WordPress Experience". I want "WordPress Experience" post not appear in Home but directly in Dear Diary Page. How is that possible?
2. I have read a [tutorial](http://moshublog.com/2007/07/26/pages-and-categories/) regarding my #1 issue but I can't grasp to that tutorial, I find it hard for me to follow.

   I tried doing it but ended up having all the *Pages* and the *Categories* on my main menu. Is it possible if in the main menu I want a certain Page and a certain Category to appear on top?
3. Is it possible to just not put the Categories in the main menu but when a post is categorized it immediately goes to this certain Page?

Comment: Are you creating your own theme? If so you can modify "the loop" to not include certain categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you need to do to make your new blog posts appear in the "Dear Diary Page"

1) Login to your wordress dashboard (I'm assuming you're using Wordpress 3.0 and above)
2) On the left under settings, click on Reading settings.
3) Smack in the centre, there will be a "Front page displays" section, this gives you control on what you would like your front page (homepage) to display and which page you'd like your blog posts to display.

Change Front Page Displays to: A static page (this is a radio button form input)

Once you've changed to "A static page", you will have access to change 2 drop down inputs below that.

1) The first drop down will give you options on which page you would like to make as your front page or in this case Homepage. **Choose Home**

2) The second drop down gives you options to choose a page where all your blog posts will go to. **Choose Dear Diary Page**

On your question on having your menu display certain pages / categories..Yes that can be done :) provided the theme you're using supports Wordpress Navigation Menus.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

If it doesn't you're going to need to add support for it in the theme which requires some theme tweaking knowledge.

If you're theme does support it, here is a link on how to use Wordpress 3.0's menu options:
http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hi arkhamDev! It really helped me but there's a problem with regards to the first drop down. I don't see 'Home'. When I created this site, Home was already there. What to do?

Comment: What if I want one of my posts to appear again in another page without it appearing to the current posts page?

Comment: You will have to write a custom template that queries posts. You could do amazing things with wordpress if you have knowledge in using WP_Query. Please vote my answer up if it did answer your question :)